# Drupal Webform Autocomplete Existing Contact Limit

Tags: webform-civicrm

Is there a limit to the amount of contacts that can be searched for on Existing Contact using autocomplete on a Drupal Webform?  I have 1+million contacts.  If I restrict the webform to a group with a limited number of contacts the autocomplete works well.  However, if I do not restrict to a small group the autocomplete fails and wants to create a new contact.

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete works and does not have a limitation (we have 900k contacts and no problems).  My mistake was in the selection of the Contact Display Field for the Existing Contact on the Drupal WebForm.  I was using the "Display Name" as the structure but I was entering search as if it was the "Sort Name"  I was getting unexpected results.  Once I started entering the search with the correct format the results were as expected and all the contacts are included.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit, no. You may need to dig in a bit more to find out why the search is not returning any results. Is it timing out? Or is it failing on permission checks?